# Other expressions for 'be down on someone'

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for other expressions or saying to describe  when someone is ill-disposed  towards someone else,  but mainly on a prejudice rather than for objective reasons.

Comment: *Prejudiced against* is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can *take against someone, be biased/have a bias against them, have/harbour {an antipathy/ill feelings} towards them*, or *have/harbour/nurse a grudge against them*.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of synonyms for "prejudiced" on [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/prejudiced), including:

> bigoted, discriminatory, dogmatic, intolerant, intransigent, one-sided, opinionated,
>   racist, sexist, xenophobic, blind, inclined, influenced, leaning, narrow,
>   preconceived, predisposed, prepossessed, presupposing, closed-minded,
>   doctrinaire, extreme, hidebound, illiberal, narrow-minded

Depending on the context, any of these should be suitable for your needs.